# Extra hot water for Jacuzzi

Tags: hot-water

We moved into an all electric (no gas or oil) house with a 40 gallon water tank and a Jacuzzi.. Looks like the Jacuzzi had never really been used.  When trying to fill it we can just barely get enough hot water for a decent bath.

Is there a an easy, inexpensive way to supplement hot water for the Jacuzzi without having to install a larger water tank?

Comment: Are you sure the existing heater is working normally?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the heater is fine.  It's a newer Rheem Prestige.

Comment: How big is the Jacuzzi?  I agree with @ThreePhaseEel tho, I'd test that both heating elements are functioning, and check how the thermostats are set.  We have a 40 gal electric tank and there is more than enough to fill our bathroom Jacuzzi, which is the size of a tall large bathtub.

Comment: Is it a Jacuzzi bathtub or a Jacuzzi hot tub.  When taking a shower do you have a good hot water.   Jacuzzi bathtubs are usually fairly large and hot tubs are huge.  You may just not have enough hot water to fill the tub

Answer (score 1):

There are three subjects to consider here.

Is your water heater working correctly. It is possible your water heater needs some maintenance as there could be too much buildup on the inside or a heating element that needs replacing. https://www.hometips.com/repair-fix/hot-water-heater-problems.html

Second the water in a water heater is usually hotter than you can use it. Then you add cold water to bring the temperature down to a usable temperature. That way a 40 gallon tank at 130 degrees should be able to produce a lot more than 40 gallons of 100 degree water. You can always turn up the temperature of the water heater. Most electric tank heaters will reach 150 or more degrees.

The last possibility is upgrading. 
For 400 dollars US you should be able to have a small tankless point of use water heater professionally installed for just the tub. They cost less than 200 dollars for just the unit if you know how to install one.

A full sized tankless water heater will cost you at least a thousand to install. If you get a gas tankless water heater either install in directly on an exterior wall, or get one that uses PVC venting. Metal vents that cheap systems use are wildly expensive.

And a larger tank water heater will cost whatever you want to spend on it plus a few hundred to professionally install. I'm seeing example prices between 500 and 1500 dollars US for a 50 gallon or larger tank depending on the efficiency. Gas water heaters have a much faster recovery rate than electric. It is possible that as 40 gallon gas water heater is all you need.

Comment: In an all electric house, he probably won't have enough electric service for a whole-house hot water heater, which are considerably less than $1000 IME.  Large tanked water heaters are (by law) heat pump types, which chill the room the water heater is in, forcing your furnace to work harder, and if that's resistive electric, you pay for the heat twice.   Of course in the summer, that's a feature :)

Comment: I have a corner Jacuzzi and a gas fired  75 gallon water heater. In order to fill the Jacuzzi with warm water I have to turn the water heater temperature up, wait for the water to heat , fill the Jacuzzi , then turn the water temperature back down. They take a lot of hot water. I am going to install a point of use electric water heater to make life easier.